# JavaFX Controller FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource());

Tags: java, javafx

I have a application that works with FXML files. Each time i want to load in another FXML file, i get a new instance of my Controller class. But i dont want that. How can i prevent this?

For instance: I just logged in on my login.fxml file and now the login.fxml file needs to close and the manageBanks.fxml file needs to show. What i programmed is that it looks at the current AnchorPane that is not NULL and gets the window from that pane, so i can close that stage. Then i load in the new .fxml file in my controller. But every time i load in a new .fxml file, the application creates a new instance of the controller. But i have an instance of my Client class in the Controller class (that is set in the constructor), and i dont want that instance to be renewed each time. I just want one instance of my Client class that the controller can speak to.

Here is my Controller class. At the bottom of this class are my methods to initialize the new stages:

```
public class Controller {
public TextField tbIban;
public TextField tbFirstName;
public TextField tbLastName;
public TextField tbPostalCode;
public TextField tbHouseNumber;
public TextField tbEmail;
public TextField tbBankName;
public TextField tbShortcut;
public TextField tbEuroIn;
public TextField tbCentIn;
public TextField tbCentOut;
public TextField tbEuroOut;
public TextField tbEuroAmount;
public TextField tbCentAmount;
public TextField tbNameReceiver;
public TextField tbIbanReceiver;
public TextArea tbDescription;
public PasswordField tbPassword;
public PasswordField tbRepeatPassword;
public Label lbName;
public Label lbIban;
public Label lbAmount;
public TableView tabelTransactions;
public TableView tabelAddresses;
public TableView tabelBanks;
public DatePicker dtpDateOfBirth;
public CheckBox cbAddToAddressBook;
public ComboBox cmbbank;
public AnchorPane screenEditAccount;
public AnchorPane screenAddressBook;
public AnchorPane screenAddressBookTransaction;
public AnchorPane screenBankAccount;
public AnchorPane screenCreateBank;
public AnchorPane screenCreateBankAccount;
public AnchorPane screenLimits;
public AnchorPane screenLogin;
public AnchorPane screenManageBanks;
public AnchorPane screenNewTransaction;

private Client client;

public Controller() {
    try {
        client = new Client();
        System.out.println("Client: Client created");
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        System.out.println("Client: Cannot create Client");
        System.out.println("Client: RemoteException: " + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public void login() {
    String iban = tbIban.getText();
    String password = tbPassword.getText();
    try {
        if (client.login(iban, password)){
            if (iban.equals("admin")) {
                changeScreenTo(Screens.MANAGEBANKS);
            } else {
                changeScreenTo(Screens.BANKACCOUNT);
            }
        } else {
            showErrorMessage("Wrong username or password.");
        }
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        showErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void logoutClient() {
    try {
        client.logout();
        changeScreenTo(Screens.LOGIN);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        showErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void logoutAdmin() {
    try {
        client.logout();
        changeScreenTo(Screens.LOGIN);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        showErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void cancelToLogin() {
    changeScreenTo(Screens.LOGIN);
}

public void createBank() {
    String name = tbBankName.getText();
    String shortcut = tbShortcut.getText();
    try {
        if (client.createBank(name, shortcut)){
            changeScreenTo(Screens.MANAGEBANKS);
        } else {
            showErrorMessage("Bank name or shortcut already excist.");
        }
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        showErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void deleteBank() {
    String bank = String.valueOf(tabelBanks.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
    String[] bankParts = bank.split(";");
    String bankName = bankParts[0];
    client.deleteBank(bankName);
}

public void createBankAccount() {
    String password = tbPassword.getText();
    String passwordRepeat = tbRepeatPassword.getText();
    String firstName = tbFirstName.getText();
    String lastName = tbLastName.getText();
    String postalCode = tbPostalCode.getText();
    int houseNumber = Integer.parseInt(tbHouseNumber.getText());
    Date dateOfBirth = Date.from(dtpDateOfBirth.getValue().atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
    String email = tbEmail.getText();
    String bankName = cmbbank.getValue().toString();
    if (password.equals(passwordRepeat) && !password.equals("")){
        if (!firstName.equals("") && !lastName.equals("") && !postalCode.equals("") && houseNumber != 0 && dateOfBirth.before(new Date()) && !email.equals("") && !bankName.equals("")){
            try {
                if (client.createBankAccount(bankName, password, firstName, lastName, postalCode, houseNumber, dateOfBirth, email)){
                    changeScreenTo(Screens.BANKACCOUNT);
                } else {
                    showErrorMessage("Something went wrong with creating your account.");
                }
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                showErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            showErrorMessage("Personal details are not valid or there is no bank selected.");
        }
    } else {
        showErrorMessage("Password can not be empty or is not the same as repeated password.");
    }
}

public void editBankAccount() {
    String password = tbPassword.getText();
    String passwordRepeat = tbRepeatPassword.getText();
    String firstName = tbFirstName.getText();
    String lastName = tbLastName.getText();
    String postalCode = tbPostalCode.getText();
    int houseNumber = Integer.parseInt(tbHouseNumber.getText());
    Date dateOfBirth = Date.from(dtpDateOfBirth.getValue().atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
    String email = tbEmail.getText();
    if (password.equals(passwordRepeat) && !password.equals("")){
        if (!firstName.equals("") && !lastName.equals("") && !postalCode.equals("") && houseNumber != 0 && dateOfBirth.before(new Date()) && !email.equals("")){
            try {
                client.editBankAccount(password, firstName, lastName, postalCode, houseNumber, dateOfBirth, email);
                changeScreenTo(Screens.BANKACCOUNT);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                showErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            showErrorMessage("Personal details are not valid.");
        }
    } else {
        showErrorMessage("Password can not be empty or is not the same as repeated password.");
    }
}

public void deleteBankAccount() {
    try {
        client.deleteBankAccount();
        changeScreenTo(Screens.LOGIN);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        showErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void cancelToBankAccount() {
    changeScreenTo(Screens.BANKACCOUNT);
}

public void editBankAccountsLimits() {
    double limitIn = Double.parseDouble(tbEuroIn.getText() + "," + tbCentIn.getText());
    double limitOut = Double.parseDouble(tbEuroOut.getText() + "," + tbCentOut.getText());
    if (limitIn > 0 && limitOut > 0){
        client.editBankAccountsLimits(limitIn, limitOut);
        changeScreenTo(Screens.BANKACCOUNT);
    } else {
        showErrorMessage("Limits can not be 0.");
    }
}

public void deleteBankAccountsAddress() {
    Address address = (Address) tabelAddresses.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    client.deleteBankAccountsAddress(address);
}

public void makeBankAccountsTransaction() {
    double amount = Double.parseDouble(tbEuroAmount.getText() + "," + tbCentAmount.getText());
    String nameReceiver = tbNameReceiver.getText();
    String ibanReceiver = tbIbanReceiver.getText();
    String description = tbDescription.getText();
    boolean addToAddress = cbAddToAddressBook.isSelected();
    if (amount > 0 && !nameReceiver.equals("") && !ibanReceiver.equals("")){
        client.makeBankAccountsTransaction(amount, nameReceiver, ibanReceiver, description, addToAddress);
        changeScreenTo(Screens.BANKACCOUNT);
    } else {
        showErrorMessage("Amount and receiver details can not be empty.");
    }
}

public void chooseAddress() {
    Address address = (Address) tabelAddresses.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    tbNameReceiver.setText(address.getName());
    tbIbanReceiver.setText(address.getIban());
    changeScreenTo(Screens.NEWTRANSACTION);
}

public void makeBankAccountsRequest() {
    double amount = Double.parseDouble(tbEuroAmount.getText() + "," + tbCentAmount.getText());
    String nameReceiver = tbNameReceiver.getText();
    String ibanReceiver = tbIbanReceiver.getText();
    String description = tbDescription.getText();
    boolean addToAddress = cbAddToAddressBook.isSelected();
    if (amount > 0 && !nameReceiver.equals("") && !ibanReceiver.equals("")){
        client.makeBankAccountsRequest(amount, nameReceiver, ibanReceiver, description, addToAddress);
        changeScreenTo(Screens.BANKACCOUNT);
    } else {
        showErrorMessage("Amount and receiver details can not be empty.");
    }
}

public void openCreateAccount() {
    changeScreenTo(Screens.CREATEBANKACCOUNT);
}

public void openAccount() {
    changeScreenTo(Screens.ACCOUNT);
}

public void openLimits() {
    changeScreenTo(Screens.LIMITS);
}

public void openAddressBook() {
    changeScreenTo(Screens.ADDRESSBOOK);
}

public void openAddressBookTransaction() {
    changeScreenTo(Screens.ADDRESSBOOKTRANSACTION);
}

public void openTransaction() {
    changeScreenTo(Screens.NEWTRANSACTION);
}

public void openCreateBank() {
    changeScreenTo(Screens.CREATEBANK);
}

private void initAccountScreen() throws IOException {
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Screens/account.fxml"));
    stage.setTitle("Account");
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.getIcons().add(new Image("file:assets/ideal_logo.jpg"));
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> changeScreenTo(Screens.BANKACCOUNT));
    stage.show();
}

private void initAddressBookScreen() throws IOException {
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Screens/addressBook.fxml"));
    stage.setTitle("Address Book");
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.getIcons().add(new Image("file:assets/ideal_logo.jpg"));
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> changeScreenTo(Screens.BANKACCOUNT));
    stage.show();
}

private void initAddressBookTransactionScreen() throws IOException {
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Screens/addressBookTransaction.fxml"));
    stage.setTitle("Address Book");
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.getIcons().add(new Image("file:assets/ideal_logo.jpg"));
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> changeScreenTo(Screens.NEWTRANSACTION));
    stage.show();
}

private void initBankAccountScreen() throws IOException {
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Screens/bankAccount.fxml"));
    stage.setTitle("Bank Account");
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.getIcons().add(new Image("file:assets/ideal_logo.jpg"));
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> logoutClient());
    stage.show();
}

private void initCreateBankScreen() throws IOException {
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Screens/createBank.fxml"));
    stage.setTitle("Create Bank");
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.getIcons().add(new Image("file:assets/ideal_logo.jpg"));
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> changeScreenTo(Screens.MANAGEBANKS));
    stage.show();
}

private void initCreateBankAccountScreen() throws IOException {
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Screens/createBankAccount.fxml"));
    stage.setTitle("Create Bank Account");
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.getIcons().add(new Image("file:assets/ideal_logo.jpg"));
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> changeScreenTo(Screens.LOGIN));
    stage.show();
}

private void initLimitsScreen() throws IOException {
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Screens/limits.fxml"));
    stage.setTitle("Limits");
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.getIcons().add(new Image("file:assets/ideal_logo.jpg"));
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> changeScreenTo(Screens.BANKACCOUNT));
    stage.show();
}

private void initLoginScreen() throws IOException {
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Screens/login.fxml"));
    stage.setTitle("Login");
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.getIcons().add(new Image("file:assets/ideal_logo.jpg"));
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> System.exit(0));
    stage.show();
}

private void initManageBanksScreen() throws IOException {
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Screens/manageBanks.fxml"));
    stage.setTitle("Manage Banks");
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.getIcons().add(new Image("file:assets/ideal_logo.jpg"));
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> logoutAdmin());
    stage.show();
}

private void initnewTransactionScreen() throws IOException {
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Screens/newTransaction.fxml"));
    stage.setTitle("New Transaction");
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.getIcons().add(new Image("file:assets/ideal_logo.jpg"));
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> changeScreenTo(Screens.BANKACCOUNT));
    stage.show();
}

private void showErrorMessage(String message){
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
    alert.setTitle("ERROR!");
    alert.setHeaderText(null);
    alert.setContentText(message);
    alert.showAndWait();
}

private void changeScreenTo(Screens screen) {
    if (screenEditAccount != null) {
        Stage currentStage = (Stage) screenEditAccount.getScene().getWindow();
        currentStage.close();
    } else if (screenAddressBook != null) {
        Stage currentStage = (Stage) screenAddressBook.getScene().getWindow();
        currentStage.close();
    } else if (screenAddressBookTransaction != null) {
        Stage currentStage = (Stage) screenAddressBookTransaction.getScene().getWindow();
        currentStage.close();
    } else if (screenBankAccount != null) {
        Stage currentStage = (Stage) screenBankAccount.getScene().getWindow();
        currentStage.close();
    } else if (screenCreateBank != null) {
        Stage currentStage = (Stage) screenCreateBank.getScene().getWindow();
        currentStage.close();
    } else if (screenCreateBankAccount != null) {
        Stage currentStage = (Stage) screenCreateBankAccount.getScene().getWindow();
        currentStage.close();
    } else if (screenLimits != null) {
        Stage currentStage = (Stage) screenLimits.getScene().getWindow();
        currentStage.close();
    } else if (screenLogin != null) {
        Stage currentStage = (Stage) screenLogin.getScene().getWindow();
        currentStage.close();
    } else if (screenManageBanks != null) {
        Stage currentStage = (Stage) screenManageBanks.getScene().getWindow();
        currentStage.close();
    } else if (screenNewTransaction != null) {
        Stage currentStage = (Stage) screenNewTransaction.getScene().getWindow();
        currentStage.close();
    }

    try {
        switch (screen) {
            case ACCOUNT:
                initAccountScreen();
                break;
            case ADDRESSBOOK:
                initAddressBookScreen();
                break;
            case ADDRESSBOOKTRANSACTION:
                initAddressBookTransactionScreen();
                break;
            case BANKACCOUNT:
                initBankAccountScreen();
                break;
            case CREATEBANK:
                initCreateBankScreen();
                break;
            case CREATEBANKACCOUNT:
                initCreateBankAccountScreen();
                break;
            case LIMITS:
                initLimitsScreen();
                break;
            case LOGIN:
                initLoginScreen();
                break;
            case MANAGEBANKS:
                initManageBanksScreen();
                break;
            case NEWTRANSACTION:
                initnewTransactionScreen();
                break;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

And here is my Main class:

```
public class ClientMain extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Screens/login.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Login");
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("file:assets/ideal_logo.jpg"));
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> System.exit(0));
    primaryStage.show();
}
}
```

Comment: "I don't want that." Of course you want that; how else would any of this work? What if you wanted to load the same FXML twice and display the results of both at the same time (think about a tabbed display, for example): if you only had one controller, you would only be able to access the fields of one of the UI structures that was loaded. It makes absolutely no sense whatsoever to share controller instances between different UIs.

Comment: Also, that is an insanely huge controller class. You should consider breaking your UI into smaller FXML files, so that you have manageable sized FXML and manageable sized controllers.

Comment: I have multiple fxml files, but 1 controller. is it a must to have a controller for each .fxml file? (sorry, im just a student)

Comment: Yes. Use a different controller *class* for each FXML file. Otherwise it is virtually impossible to keep track of what is initialized and what is not initialized in any particular controller instance.

Comment: @James_D okay, thank you, i am going to change that. maybe that will already solve my issue

Comment: It will probably make it clearer what you need to do to solve the issue.

Comment: but if i do it like that, what is then the best way to change between stages(screens)?

Comment: You load the new FXML file, and display it in a window. That shouldn't really change.

Comment: You can consider using a "View model" to represent the state of the view; in particular which "screen" is currently displayed. There was a blog post on this a while ago at Oracle, that post is no longer available afaict but there is a youtube here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5GsdaZWDcdY and you can look at the author's github repo here: https://github.com/acaicedo/JFX-MultiScreen

Comment: @James_D, i watched the youtube video and it helped me out alot! thank you bro!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you load an FXML file, you get new instances of the UI elements defined in the FXML file. For example, your FXML file apparently has a large collection of `<TextField>` elements; for each of those `<TextField>` elements you get a new `TextField` instance created each time you load the FXML.

Since the controller typically has references to the UI elements defined in the FXML file, and/or has event handlers specific to those elements, a controller *instance* is specific to the *instance* of a UI loaded from a specific call to `FXMLLoader.load()`.

As a consequence, it really makes no sense at all to share a single controller instance among multiple UIs loaded from multiple calls to `FXMLLoader.load()`. You should have a different controller instance for each, which is the default behavior.